# integrating simulink into a matlab script

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have the following problem. I want to integrate a simulink model into a matlab script, to do different things in a loop with the simulink part of the program.
The program below actually does what I was hoping for when I defined the parameters I used into the simulink model in the workspace. But this solution does not satisfy me. I want to pass the parameters as the second value of the `sim` function. Unfortunately I can't get my head around this. I literally copied the part to create a structure from the matlab site where the following code sample has been given.

```
myStruct = Simulink.Parameter;
myStruct.Value = struct('number',1,'units',24);
myStruct.CoderInfo.StorageClass = 'ExportedGlobal';
```

Unfortunately I get the following error `Input argument "m_startSpeed" is undefined.` because in my script the parameter `m_startSpeed` is a value which I input when running the script.

```
function [optBreakPoint] = computeBreakPoint(m_startSpeed, m_endSpeed, m_length)
    myStruct = Simulink.Parameter;
    myStruct.Value = struct('m' , 1500, 'R' , 0.25, 'mi' , 1, 'f' , 0.1, 'F' , 50000,'BreakForce' , -10, 'startSpeed' , m_startSpeed, 'breakPoint' , m_length);
    myStruct.CoderInfo.StorageClass = 'ExportedGlobal';
    endSpeed = m_endSpeed;
    while(1)
        [T, X, Y] = sim('car', myStruct);
        optBreakPoint = breakPoint;
        break;
    end
    plot(T, X);
end
```

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The input structure (i.e. the second input to the sim function), contains information about how to simulate the model (i.e. information from the Model Configuration dialog, or Configuration Set), not parameters of the blocks in the model.

Look at either

```
>> doc sim
```

or http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/sim.html
for an example of what that structure should look like.

Block parameters are obtained from a workspace - by default the Base Workspace, but you can specify this by changing the models 'SrcWorkspace" parameter.

This property is also discussed on the above documentation pages.